# Why does this merge sort code gives zeroes instead of given elements in the resulting array

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

When I try to print the left and right subarrays some of the elements become zero instead of actual elements present in the array. The `merge` function works fine but the sorting function doesn't seem to work.

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] A) {
    int n = A.length;
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int mid = n / 2;
    int[] left = new int[mid];
    int[] right = new int[n - mid];
    for (int i = 0; i < mid - 1; i++) {
        left[i] = A[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(left));
    for (int j = 0; j < n - mid; j++) {
        right[j] = A[j + mid];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(right));
    mergeSort(left); 
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(left, right, A);
}

public static void merge(int[] l, int[] r, int[] A) {
    int nl = l.length;
    int nr = r.length;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < nl && j < nr) {
        if (l[i] <= r[i]) {
            A[k] = l[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            A[k] = r[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < nl) {
        A[k] = l[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < nr) {
        A[k] = r[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int j=mid;j<n;j++){
            right[j]=A[j];
        }
this should work

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

The loop to initialize the `left` subarray stops before the last element, you should write:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        left[i] = A[i];
    }
```

Comment: @RuchiSharma: did this answer help you? you can accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.